Firebase crashlytics not binding while firebase messaging working as excepted
I have a .net maui app that I want to connect to firebase crashlytics and messaging. I have managed to send notification successfuly but the crashlytics part doesn't bind to my app as I don't see that "App detected message"
I followed this link
https://dev.to/vhugogarcia/firebase-crashlytics-in-net-maui-57jp
MauiProgram
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
                Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Init();
                Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
                Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SendUnsentReports();
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, bundle) => {
                Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(activity);
            }));
#endif
        });

string.xml
<resources>
    <string name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.mapping_file_id">none</string>
    <string name="google_app_id">omitted on purpose</string>
    <string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">2.0</string>
</resources>

and my .csproj
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
        <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Core" Version="121.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics" Version="118.3.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

I'm using a different version of Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics as I had some downgrade detected conflicts
Also where are some logs from the output window
[FirebaseApp] Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
[name.bookmateui] Verification of com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.time.Clock com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.time.TimeModule_EventClockFactory.get() took 112.035ms (44.63 bytecodes/s) (1408B approximate peak alloc)
[FirebaseCrashlytics] Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.3.2 for com.companyname.bookmateui
[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization successful

PS
I have only tested on android

You can check this issue about the Firebase Crashlytics doesn't detect any bugs (NET 8).

I was missing a line when initializing firebase
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, bundle) => {
                Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(activity);
                FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true); --- THIS LINE
}));

and I was running an emulator in debug mode witch I think it interfered with the exception logging process so run without and it should work
and I removed
 <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Core" Version="121.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics" Version="118.3.2" />

and I have added without any platform restrictions (Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics" Version="2.0.3" />


